# Integral of square root with quadratics, trouble with substitution due to 1/(2x)

Tags: integration

I have a following case to integrate:
$$\int{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac12x-\frac1{2x}\right)^2}dx}$$

I tried following the steps that are suggested for integrating square roots with enclosed sum of quadratics, but I am having trouble with the substitution, due to the $\frac1{2x}$ part.

I tried calculating the square before doing the substitution, but the fraction that is causing the problems with substitution remains.

This is what I used to look for integration methods:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationStrategy.aspx

I tried following the suggestions from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23DbI7ZHOwY
but I do not have simple $x^2$, and I can't find simple substitution that would transform it into such.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Edit:
After a nice hint from Tired I noticed, that this can be written as complete square $\frac14(x+x^{-1})$ and then the solution becomes trivial and no susbstitution is required at all. Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider trig substitution?

Comment: i would suggest a substitution $x=e^y$ together with the fact that $\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y)=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint: for the integrand we get $$\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{4x^2}$$

Comment: Nice observation (+1)